# How to put two list of web element in HashMap?

Tags: java, selenium

I have two lists of Selenium web elements. Both lists contain string values. How can I put them in a hash map, verify if "Previous Amount" and "Total Amount" is present and both of them have precision 2?

Table
[image]

I currently have written the following code:

```
@FindBy(How=How.Xpath, using =“xpath to header”)
private static List<WebElement> header;

@FindBy(how=How.Xpath, using =“xpath to headerValue”)
private static List<WebElement> headerValue;

public HasMap<String,String> verifyHeaderAndValue()
{
    HasMap<String,String> hedDetails = new HasMap<>();
    for(int I = 0; I < hedDetails.size(); I++)
    {
        hedDetails.put(header.get(I).getText(), headerValue.get(I).getText());
    }
    return hedDetails;
}
```

Comment: `List<WebElement>` doesn't contain `String`s, it contains `WebElement`. Are you referring to the text inside the element, e.g. `element.getText()`? It sounds like you are describing your solution to the problem. What I would suggest is that you describe the problem *first* and then describe your attempted solution to the problem. Sometimes there are better or more efficient ways to do what you are attempting but if you don't describe the original problem well, we will end up trying to fix your approach instead of providing the better approach.

Comment: Hello thanks for your quick replay. Yes I am referring to Web element inner string. I have tried above solution. But I want to verify that has map with web table values. Header List of web element contains List of header and value List of element contains List of value. I want to verify that value is not null.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to fix your code. There are multiple typos and syntax problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here value control code for Previous Amount, for Total Amount you can use the same(TestNG Asserts):

```
String prevAmount = headDetails.get("Previous Amount");
Assert.assertNotNull(prevAmount, "Previous Amount found");
//if amount can NOT be negative
Assert.assertTrue(prevAmount.matches("^\\d+\\.\\d{2}$"), "Has 2 precision");
//if amount can be negative
Assert.assertTrue(prevAmount.matches("\\d+\\.\\d{2}$"), "Has 2 precision");
```

Comment: "^\\d+\\.\\d{2}$" and "\\d+\\.\\d{2}$" didn't work for me, however "\d+\.\d{2}$" does.

Comment: @theGuy Strange, idea says `\\\`

Comment: Hi when I try above code String values come as a null.

Comment: I think String prevAmount = headerDetails.get(“Previous Amount”); doesn’t work properly can you please help me resolve it @sers

Comment: After filling hashmap print keys and values. Let see if it’s correct

Comment: I was using system.out.println(headDetails.keyset()); but not print anything  I have used this right after for loop

Comment: Check your locators. Your code. There is no problem with code

Comment: Thanks I found the problem and solved it , I made a mistake in for loop that’s why it coming as a null now I have fixed it and working fine.

Comment: I have previous amount value is dynamic some time is 0.00 and some time like 10,000.00 so how can I make assertion on that ? @sers

Comment: @sers  can u give me an idea about above comments

Comment: Actually I try last  code with value 0.00 it wasn’t work. I want it to be work if I have dynamic values like with different values some times 78.09 or 999,98.00 or any other value how would I check if that values contains precision 2 at the end

Comment: @sers can u help me with above requirement

Comment: @SnehalThakkar yes you're right, `^\d+\.\d{2}$|^\d+[,]?\d+\.\d{2}$` this should work

Comment: Double slash: `^\\d+\\.\\d{2}$|^\\d+[,]?\\d+\\.\\d{2}$`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179415/discussion-between-sers-and-snehal-thakkar).

Comment: Is there a way we can split on “.” And check it has a precision two?@sers

Comment: @SnehalThakkar regex I gave you checks precision. Why you want to split

Answer (score 0):

You had some typos/mistakes in your code so it wouldn't compile. I've fixed those below.

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "")
private static List<WebElement> header;

@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "")
private static List<WebElement> headerValue;
```

Your method isn't actually verifying anything so I changed the name to get* because that's what it actually does... gets the `HashMap` of the mix of values.

The first thing you should do is to ensure that the two `List`s are of the same size or the comparison fails immediately. One issue in your code is that you were looping to the size of `headDetails`. `headDetails` is a variable that you just created so it's size will be 0 and the `for` loop will never run. You should reference the size of either `header` or `headerValue`. After the size check, they will both be of equal size so it doesn't really matter which one you use.

```
public HashMap<String, String> getHeaderAndValue()
{
    // need to make sure that the two element lists are the same size or the comparison should/will fail
    Assert.assertEquals(header.size(), headerValue.size());

    HashMap<String, String> headDetails = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < header.size(); i++)
    {
        headDetails.put(header.get(i).getText(), headerValue.get(i).getText());
    }

    return headDetails;
}
```

Comment: I have update my question a little bit if you can answer it Jeff
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52122537/how-to-get-list-of-webtable-in-to-a-hasmap-and-verify-the-values

Comment: You have created an entirely new question to ask the same thing. You need to delete the new question and edit this question and add the new info.

Comment: Sure I’m going to remove it now

Comment: Is there a way that we can split on “.” And Check that value has a precision 2 ?@JeffC